# Php regex length limit

Tags: php, regex

I have such String

```
/member/%E9%BB%91%E7%9C%BC%E5%9C%88%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E5%95%8A/home
```

And I use this pattern

```
preg_match_all("/member\/(?<$authorcode>(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+)/",$sourcestring,$matches2);
```

But what I get is

```
%E9%BB%91%E7%9C%BC%E5%9C%88%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E5
```

So, how to solve it?

Comment: What is `$authorcode` and what do you want to get; `%E9%BB%91%E7%9C%BC%E5%9C%88%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E5%95%8A`?

Comment: Yes, But I only get `%E9%BB%91%E7%9C%BC%E5%9C%88%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E5`

Comment: try `urldecode()`ing that string first, then doing the match (you'll need to handle chinese characters)

Comment: Thank you, but I wonder why this problem happend

Comment: The browser will encode the characters it does not understand. A very simple example is %20

Comment: You have 2 capture groups, make the second one non-capture; `member\/(?<test>(?:%[0-9A-Z]{2})+)`. https://regex101.com/r/kI7gQ7/1

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry I have made a stupid mistake, I read this string from file, but the length I use is wrong, so I only get `%E9%BB%91%E7%9C%BC%E5%9C%88%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E5%95%8A` from file.